# Javascript composition prototype function

Tags: javascript, prototype

```
Function.prototype.times = function(val){
        var that = this;
        return function (arg) {
            if(val == 0){
                return that.call(this,arg);
            }
            else{
                var newArg = that.call(this,arg);
                var newVal = val - 1;
                return that.call(that.times,newVal,newArg);
            }
        }
    }
    var add_two = function (num) { return num + 2; };
    var add_six = add_two.times(3);
    alert(add_six(2));
```

Can somebody help me with explaining why this code is not working? Thank you!

Comment: add_six is not a function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of problems with this, here's a fixed version:

```
Function.prototype.times = function(val){
    var that = this;
    return function (arg) {
        if(val == 1) {
            return that.call(this,arg);
        } else{
            var newArg = that.call(this,arg);
            var newVal = val - 1;
            return that.times.call(that,newVal)(newArg);
        }
    }
}
var add_two = function (num) { return num + 2; };
var add_six = add_two.times(3);
alert(add_six(2)); // 8
```

Comment: why not just return val*newArg-newVal*arg; ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out.
[Link](http://jsfiddle.net/8Z8jr/)

Basically add_six is not a function but reference of a function.
 Check the code below

```
 alert(typeof add_six(2));
```